# Лишние запросы prevel.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

При открытии приложения с локального сервера (на express.js) кроме непосредственно самих файлов (index.html, index.js и sum.js) почему-то грузится еще дофига левых js файлов (см. картинку). Помогите пожалуйста убрать это. Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы удалить файл, необходимо знать, где он используется, так как удаление файла может привести к поломке функционала. На ваш вопрос сложно дать ответ, так как никто, кроме создателя этого сайта знает, как там все устроено и для чего там грузятся все эти файлы.

Comment: Судя по логу запросов - инициатор запросов `prevel.js`. Просто так убрать запросы вряд ли получится. Как вам уже сказали - удаление может привести к поломке функционала. Возможно стоит добавить детали в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался с таким же.
Это скорее всего какой-то установленный экстеншн инжектит этот скрипт.
У меня вот этот был виновником https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mate-translate-%E2%80%93-translat/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke?hl=en-US

Comment: Зарегистрировался специально, чтоб подтвердить ответ от Yaroslav - у меня также расширение Mate Translate добавляет эти запросы. Я запрещаю всем расширениям работать в приватном режиме и отслеживаю запросы нужного мне сайта в приватном режиме браузера.<br>
PS. Хрен лайк поставишь просто так или прокомментируешь, поэтому пишу отдельным ответом)<br>
PPS. И через 3 года)